# Drawing cloth or surfaces in openGL ES?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to draw a 3d kitchen table with openGL, I'm having trouble in representing the tablecloth over it. I would like to be able to deform the tablecloth with gestures such as swipes. I want to go with a 3d strategy, drawing my tablecloth using a NURB surface, but seems like openGL ES has no support for it.

Any suggestions ?

Any 3d engine for iPhone with features which could help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for a cloth simulation?

Do you need to deform the cloth arbitrarily, or do you have only a set number of "swipes" or deforms you're after? If so, I'd suggest maybe faking it using morph targets. Just make your tablecloth in the DCC package of your choice and set up the deformed positions as morph targets, and blend between them at run time. This will have better performance than a cloth sim of equivalent quality (probably). I'm pretty sure whatever Engines that are our there will support morph targets. (I don't know what's out there - sorry!)